# Calculating linear regression model repeatedly and efficiently over a sliding window

Tags: java, statistics, linear-regression, data-analysis

Given a large dataset of float values over time (with variable spacing) and a sliding window size of a certain duration, I am looking for a method to calculate a linear regression model (like least squares) over the datapoints inside the window for each position of the sliding window.

[image: Graph]

Let's say the window starts on the left and moves right. Over time, datapoints enter the window on the right and leave it on the left. Whenever that happens, the regression model should be updated to reflect the new set of datapoints.

This update operation should be significantly faster than just recalculating the model. And it is ok to keep some metadata together with the current model to aid in updating it. But the memory size of this metadata should be significantly less then the size of all datapoints in the window.

Does such a method exist? How does it work? Is there a Java library for it?

Comment: Sounds like a Kalman filter to me.

Comment: See e.g. [javadocs on KalmanFilter](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/filter/KalmanFilter.html)

Answer (score 0):

After more research I realized that the [SimpleRegression class from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math4/stat/regression/SimpleRegression.html#append-org.apache.commons.math4.stat.regression.SimpleRegression-) actually has all the described features.